# QOpenGLWidget does not show on wayland: Protocol error

Tags: c++, qt, wayland, qt6, qtopengl

I was trying to make some tests with the QOpenGLWidget class (Qt6), and I wrote the following main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QOpenGLWidget win(nullptr);
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

But, when executing on ubuntu/wayland, I get the following error:

```
The Wayland connection experienced a fatal error: Protocol error
```

If I set the following environment variable, works fine (a black window is shown):

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
```

Do I need to set some additional settings to have it working on wayland natively?
Or is there something wrong with my system configuration?

I am building with cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(FirstQtWindow)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Gui OpenGLWidgets)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_executable(first-qt-window
    main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    first-qt-window
    PUBLIC
        OpenGL::GLU
        Qt6::Core
        Qt6::OpenGLWidgets)
```

Comment: test it on a X11 or Windows system.

Comment: @amacoder works fine on windows. I can't test it on x11 right now

Comment: upload your code or x11 unix executable to internet. i can test.

Comment: tested right now also on x11, and it works as expected.